# How can I add a telegram.User object to a telegram.Chat using python-telegram-bot API to build tests

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I can create a User object `user = telegram.User(id=123, first_name="Foo", is_bot=False)` and a chat object `chat = Chat(id=0, type="group")`. How do I add the created user object to the group chat? There doesn't seem to be a method like chat.add_user.

Edit:

This is to build tests, I assume there is a way to do it for testing purposes? I know I cannot do this in production

Answer (score 0):

You can't add users to a chat via the Bot API. All available methods are listed in the official documentation at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. Everything not listed there can not be done with telegram bots.

Comment: Sorry I should have said this was for building tests. Is there a way to associate a user with a chat object when building tests?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "associate a user with a chat object"? What difference does it make that you want to do this in the context of unit tests?